# Moment of Inertia of Rhombus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

Quick question on how I would calculate the moment of inertia of the following rhombus. The question states:

The rhombus can be split into four right angled triangles by using the vertical and
horizontal lines of symmetry. By considering the upper, right triangle, calculate the
moment of inertia of the rhombus for its centre of mass C expressed as a function of
d and m.

I am confused with the wording 'By considering the upper, right triangle'. Does this mean I must first calculate the centre of mass of the upper right triangle of the rhombus and from this point calculate the moment of inertia of the whole rhombus in regards to this new centre of mass?

Many thanks for any of your comments.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should first calculate the moment of inertia of the above right triangle with respect to the point $C$.

[image]

Then conclude $I_{\text{rhombus}} = 4I_{\text{triangle}}$ by symmetry.

Comment: This is dangerously close to a complete answer.

Comment: @garyp You're right, I removed some details.

Comment: Thank you! Should be able to solve now :)